# ionic 2 Passing Data From ion-item-options

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

How can i send item data from ion-item-options button in home page to map page.

I want to send this item data **{{info.map}}**

**Home.html**

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let info of infos">

      <ion-item>

        {{info.title}} 
         {{info.map}} 

      </ion-item>

    <ion-item-options>
           <button ion-button icon-only color="light" (click)="Map()">
              <ion-icon name="map"></ion-icon>
            </button>
```

I have this code from my home.html

And want to send here
**map.ts**

```
let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(**HERE**);
```

Comment: what is `Map()` function doing? are you navigating to map.ts?

Comment: Yes navigating to map page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send your data as a parameter in `click` event.

```
 <button ion-button icon-only color="light" (click)="Map(info.map)">
     <ion-icon name="map"></ion-icon>
 </button>
```

Define `Map()` as `Map(data:any)` and send the object as parameter through the NavController.

```
Map(data:any){
  this.nav.push(MapPage,{FirstParam:data});
}
```

Comment: I apologize for keeping you busy, What do i need to write

`Map(data:any){ `
 
`this.nav.push(MapPage,{'here' }); }`

When i try it with `{FirstParam: info.map}`
It looks empty

Comment: Sry about the late response..clearly we are in different timezones.